# Playing audio file in native audio player

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to play audio which resides in [this](http://www.fundamentalalvarado.com/assets/sermons/bible-doctrine-series/032413-pm-The%20Doctrine%20of%20the%20Devil.mp3) place, in android native mp3 player. I tried using MediaPlayer class, but didn't work. Tried using intent, but it worked on only samsung set. Please suggest some good material where I can play the linked mp3 audio in android native application. the path is fundamentalalvarado.com/assets/sermons/bible-doctrine-series/032413-pm-The Doctrine of the Devil.mp3. Does the space makes any difference.I am new to android.

Here is the code.

package com.example.audiotest;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, Uri.parse("http://www.fundamentalalvarado.com/assets/sermons/bible-doctrine-series/032413-pm-The%20Doctrine%20of%20the%20Devil.mp3"));
//      playIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(playIntent, "Select an audio player"));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. do you handle the space in the file name ? 2. show your codes.

Comment: what you tried  ? past some part of code .

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: How come the url can be played easily in windows phone with its native applicatoin? I'm not arguing, but it works fine in that one. Why is that a problem in android? Want to know since I'm newbie.

Comment: Windows Phone OS is not equal to Android OS. Works fine in WP does not mean it will work on other OS.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: I tried handling the spaces. Still the same problem. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: why don't you use `MediaPlayer` to play your MP3 ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Please provide a good tutorial for playing using MediaPlayer. I tried few, but none of them worked.

Comment: you should at least look into Android official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html